# UIDocumentInteractionController does not open files from Documents/Inbox folder

Tags: ios, uidocumentinteraction

Our iOS app implements the 'Open in' option. When the user selects our app to open a file we show the file with UIDocumentInteractionController.

In the app delegate we have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{

    if (url != nil && [url isFileURL])
    {
        [self.viewController handleDocumentOpenURL:url];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

And then

```
- (void)handleDocumentOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[url path]];
  if (fileExists)
    NSLog(@"The file exists");
  else
    NSLog(@"The file doesn't exists");

  UIDocumentInteractionController *controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
  controller.delegate = self;
  [controller presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
}
```

`-(UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller` returns self

It was working well with iOS 7 but since iOS 8 it doesn't work (on iOS 8). On iOS 8 the previewer shows only a grey screen with the name of the file.

These files are saved by the system in the Documents/Inbox folder.

If we copy the file to another folder and try to show that copy it works... Pretty weird

Any ideas?

Comment: Share the code please. There are so many reasons that could happen but can't be sure without seeing how arrived there